Confusion about flow network definition and orientation of edges.
A network is a simple directed graph with two distinguished vertices $a,z$ such that $d^-(a)=0=d^+(z)$ (in and out-degree in the sense of a directed graph). The weight of an edge is called its capacity. A $flow$ in $G$ is a function $E(G)\to\mathbb{R}_0^+$. We define the in-flow of $v$ and the out-flow of $v$ respectively:
$$f^{-}(v)=\sum_{u\in V(G)}f(u,v)~~~~~~\text{ and }~~~~~~f^{+}(v)=\sum_{u\in V(G)}f(v,u),$$
where $f(x,y)=0$ if $xy\not\in E(G)$.
Here comes the first question. Since the graph is directed, then if $f(u,v)$ is, for example, $f(u,v)=0$, then $f(v,u)=0$ since it is a simple directed graph so we cannot have parallel edges $(uv\in E(G)\implies vu\not\in E(G))$?
The next question is what confuses me the most. I couldn't find a good source that goes in detail here and this might be a trivial thing I'm missing.
Given a network $G$ and $u,v\in V(G)$, we say that $uv\in E(G)$ is proper. It is improper if $vu\in E(G)$.
In what sense do you say an edge is proper? With respect to some order? If $vu$ is an edge of the graph, why isn't that one the proper, for instance?
I can see this definitions makes more sense if we are on a path from $a$ to $z$ let's say, so a "backward" wedge would be improper, for instance, the edge $uv$:
$$P:u\leftarrow v\to w$$
At first I thought you said an edge is proper or improper with respect the vertex you "are on", but doesn't make sense when then I studied the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. On many sources I see this same definition without answers.
Thanks in advance.

Please ask only one question per post.

If you have already consulted one or more textbooks for their definitions, I suggest citing the textbook you consulted and listing what definition they give / you are using.

Also please cite the source of the definition of "proper" that you are using.

It depends on what definition/formalization of network and flow you use.
One standard formulation is found in Wikipedia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Flows and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Definition).  By those definitions, the answer is: Yes, you can and should have edges that are a reverse of each other.  This definition of a network requires that if $(u,v) \in E$ then we also have $(v,u) \in E$, and this definition of a flow requires that $f(u,v) = -f(v,u)$.  In particular, a network can (and should) contain both the edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$.  The notion of "proper" is never defined nor needed.
In another source (Algorithms by Erickson), these issues are basically brushed under the rug, perhaps for pedagogical reasons.  A network is defined as a directed graph with source and target (no requirement that it be a simple graph).  Therefore, I suppose you could have both edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ as part of a flow network, though real-world applications probably typically won't.  Also, the notion of "proper" is never introduced nor needed.
There may well be other formalizations.

Side note: I don't think you are using the term "parallel edges" correctly.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges.
